Movie about a genius boy
So this movie, i probably watched it around 5 years ago or something. 
It was about this kid who is very smart and started talking since he was 3 years old. He goes to normal school then he goes to university when he is around 11. 
He does a DNA test to find his biological father who happens to be a genius. at the end of the movie the boy explains his genius is because of his film like memory. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released?  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

"started talking since he was 3 years old" - don't most kids know how to talk by the time they're 3?

Possibly Jesus Henry Christ from 2011. It stars Toni Collette.
Plot synopsis:

Henry (Jason Spevack) is a precocious 11-year old boy, conceived in a petri-dish, raised by his single mother, Patricia (Toni Collette), and is smarter than all of his peers. However, the one question he can't answer is, who is his father? Henry's attempts at locating his father lead him to Dr. Slavkin O'Hara (Michael Sheen), a university professor [...].

Trailer:



Full movie:



